# Exporting from Database to Excel using JXL RowsExceeded Error

Tags: java, database, excel, jdbc, jxl

I have written a piece of code that is supposed to connect to a database and fetch all the data from a table and export it to Excel using JXL. But I am getting a RowsExceeded error when trying to run it. It is dynamic and creates the number of rows and columsn required by itself.I have even used a .csv extension for the file. Can anybody help on this?? The main part of the code is written below:

```
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        System.out.println("Created DB Connection....");

            File exlFile = new File("c:/TestSheet.csv");
            WritableWorkbook writableWorkbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(exlFile);

            WritableSheet writableSheet = writableWorkbook.createSheet(
                    "Sheet1", 0);
            System.out.println("EXCEL FILE CREATED!!");
            String Query="select * from "+"Endpoint_Attributes";
            System.out.println(Query);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(Query);


        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

       for(int i=1;i<=columnCount;i++){

           Label Headings = new Label(i-1, 0, rsmd.getColumnName(i));
           writableSheet.addCell(Headings);

       }
       int RowCount = 0;

       while(rs.next())
       {
           RowCount=rs.getRow();

           for(int i=1;i<=columnCount;i++){

               Label CellData = new Label(i-1,RowCount,rs.getString(i));
               writableSheet.addCell(CellData);


           }
       }System.out.println("Successfully Exported");
       writableWorkbook.write();
       writableWorkbook.close();

}
```

}

Comment: Could you include the exact text of the error? Where is the error being raised? Can you come up with a simple example code that reproduces the error? Check out this [guide on how to ask good questions on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: sure.... the code is actually working pretty well for smaller tables... the table that I was trying to access is huge and thats the reason I am getting the following exception I guess:
code `
 jxl.write.biff.RowsExceededException: The maximum number of rows permitted on a worksheet been exceeded
 at jxl.write.biff.WritableSheetImpl.getRowRecord(WritableSheetImpl.java:1214)
 at jxl.write.biff.WritableSheetImpl.addCell(WritableSheetImpl.java:1151)
 at DBConnector.DBConnection(DBConnector.java:90)
 at ExcelReportGenerator$2.actionPerformed(ExcelReportGenerator.java:107) `